# I need a better understanding of my if statement

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim PageInput As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each elem As HtmlElement In PageInput
        If elem.GetAttribute("name") = "wdf_origin" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", FromTXT.Text)
        End If
        If elem.GetAttribute("name") = "wdf_destination" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", ToTXT.Text)
        End If
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            elem.GetAttribute("id") = "oneway" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("checked", RadioButton1.Checked) Then
            elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdfdate1" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", DateTimePicker1.Text)
        End If
        If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            elem.GetAttribute("id") = "return" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("checked", RadioButton2.Checked) Then
            elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdfdate1" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", DateTimePicker1.Text) Then
            elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdfdate2" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", DateTimePicker2.Text)
        End If
    Next

    Dim PageInput2 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")
    For Each elem As HtmlElement In PageInput2
        If elem.GetAttribute("id") = "adults" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", AdultsTXT.Text)
        End If
        If elem.GetAttribute("id") = "children" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", ChildrenTXT.Text)
        End If
        If elem.GetAttribute("id") = "infants" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", InfantsTXT.Text)
        End If
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdftime1" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", Time1TXT.Text)
        End If
        If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdftime2" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", Time2TXT.Text) Then
            elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdftime1" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", Time1TXT.Text)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

At the moment, I am getting a this error

> expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment

on the `elem.GetAttribute(" ")` lines. Along with it saying it expects the statement to end on some of the `Then`s. Can I not set certain methods within if statements so that they include certain text boxes? I'm trying to get the `RadioButtons` to send certain text boxes depends on which `RadioButton` is selected.

Any suggestions or resources would be helpful.

Comment: if if if if if if if end end end end end end end if if if if if if if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that each Then has a coresponding If, also it looks like you actually need to be using the [`AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) and [`ElseIf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) operators to do what you are wanting. The reason that you are getting the "expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment" errors are because you are trying to assign the value to your GetAttribute because of the lack of an If statement.

See if this works better for you.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim PageInput As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each elem As HtmlElement In PageInput
        If elem.GetAttribute("name") = "wdf_origin" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", FromTXT.Text)
        End If
        If elem.GetAttribute("name") = "wdf_destination" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", ToTXT.Text)
        End If
        If RadioButton1.Checked then
            If elem.GetAttribute("id") = "oneway" Then
                elem.SetAttribute("checked", CStr(RadioButton1.Checked))
            ElseIf elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdfdate1" Then
                elem.SetAttribute("value", DateTimePicker1.Text)
            End If
        End If

        If RadioButton2.Checked then
            If elem.GetAttribute("id") = "return" Then
                elem.SetAttribute("checked", RadioButton2.Checked.ToString)
            ElseIf elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdfdate1" Then
                elem.SetAttribute("value", DateTimePicker1.Text)
            ElseIf elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdfdate2" Then
                elem.SetAttribute("value", DateTimePicker2.Text)
            End If
        End If

    Next

    Dim PageInput2 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")
    For Each elem As HtmlElement In PageInput2
        If elem.GetAttribute("id") = "adults" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", AdultsTXT.Text)
        End If
        If elem.GetAttribute("id") = "children" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", ChildrenTXT.Text)
        End If
        If elem.GetAttribute("id") = "infants" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", InfantsTXT.Text)
        End If
        If RadioButton1.Checked AndAlso elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdftime1" Then
            elem.SetAttribute("value", Time1TXT.Text)
        End If
        If RadioButton2.Checked Then
            If elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdftime2" Then
                elem.SetAttribute("value", Time2TXT.Text)
            ElseIf elem.GetAttribute("id") = "wdftime1" Then
                elem.SetAttribute("value", Time1TXT.Text)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: +1: `CStr(RadioButton1.Checked)` could be written as `"True"`. Also `RadioButton2.Checked.ToString`

Comment: Heh...it worked for one way but the RadioButton2 is having some trouble. I need the fields listed under RadioButton2 to all be sent. If I change the 'ElseIf' to an 'If', will that end up including the other fields I want RadioButton2 to send?

Comment: @user1813751 looking at your logic it appeared that you were checking the id for 2 different values which is why I used the elseif statement . Which Radiobutton2 conditional are you having issues with?

Comment: I'm presuming both of them because if we are to do an elseif, it wouldn't submit DateTimePicker2.Text and Time1TXT.Text.

Comment: @user1813751 I think I see problem with first one, the second one looks ok. What it say is if RadioButton2 is checked then if id is equal to wdftime2 then set its value to Time2TXT.Text else if id is wdfTime1 then set the value to Time1TXT.Text. I will make an edit in a few minutes

Comment: By the way, you wouldn't happen to have a tutorial on how to adjust the DateTimePicker1 & DateTimePicker2 would you? They ate DateTimePickers of course, but I want to be able to resubmit them two more times. One sending the previous day indicated and the other for day after indicated. The two I indicated are gonna go into separate webbrowsers. 

If I put "DateTimePicker1.Text = DateTimePicker1.Text.AddDays(1)" and "DateTimePicker1.Text = DateTimePicker1.Text.AddDays(-1)" before the line of radiobutton1, will that work?

Comment: Then I wonder if I should change DateTimePicker to a value instead of text.

Comment: @user1813751 first of all the `DateTimePicker.Text` value does not have the AddDays method, you need to use the Value Attribute. I am not sure what you have for Your `DateTimePicker.Format` Property, I would use the adjusted Value. Something like this: `elem.SetAttribute("value", DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString)` You have a lot of options for the `.ToString` Method including a Custom Format. It all depends on what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Yeah, seem's to not have worked. I'm guessing it's because I've left the DateTimePickers to their default format?

Comment: @user1813751 Look at your Property Viewer for the control, see what the Format is, I believe that the default is the LongDateFormat so try .ToLongDateString instead.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thank you so much! I've been pulling my hair out over this project for class, for months.

Comment: @user1813751 You are welcome, glad to have been of some help. Don't forget to accept the answers that answer the questions that you ask by checking the checkMark at the left of the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors. You should have an `If` before every `Then`, like you do in the first one. I'm not sure what the logic you're after is, but you can use `and` or `or` between expressions if you need to, or you can nest an `If` `End If` block inside of another.